# can not find python36.dll when install python3.6.2

Tags: python

I'm installing python3.6.2 on windows10 64bit, but a messagebox shows "because can not find python36.dll, can not continue to execute code. Reinstalling the program may solve the problem", what should I do to solve this problem? thanks.

[this is the error messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Cwo.png)

if I click the confirm button, the install program continue to show the error message several times, the shows "setup was successful", then if I run "python" in command prompt, it will show the error messagebox again.